# Three nonlinear equations with three unknowns and plot one of the unknowns with a parameter?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

There are three nonlinear equations of unknowns `h1`, `h2` and `h3`, and I need to plot the unknowns with varying $\sigma_1$.

```
1.*10^-6 ==0.0001 h1^2 + 100 h1 ((51 h2^2)/1400 - Subscript[σ, 1])^2

1.*10^-6 ==4.*10^-6 h2^2 + 4 h2^2 (0.00104167 + (6 h1^2)/7 - (33 h2^2)/350 - 
Subscript[σ, 1])^2

1.*10^-6 ==1.6*10^-7 h3^2 + 0.16 h3^2 (0.001 + 0.00462963 h1^2 + 0.00204167 
h2^2 - 0.0125 h3^2)^2
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Try `FindRoot`.

Comment: What is the range of values for $\sigma_1$?

Comment: the range of sigma 1 is from -0.008 to 0.008

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher how can i use FindRoot

Answer (score 4):

For problems like this, I like to recast it as an ODE where the parameter is the independent variable. Here is how I would do this for your question.

**Equations**

First, make the dependence of the dependent variables explicit:

```
eqns = {
    1.*10^-6==0.0001 h1^2+100 h1 ((51 h2^2)/1400-Subscript[σ,1])^2,
    1.*10^-6==4.*10^-6 h2^2+4 h2^2 (0.00104167+(6 h1^2)/7-(33 h2^2)/350-Subscript[σ,1])^2,
    1.*10^-6==1.6*10^-7 h3^2+0.16 h3^2 (0.001+0.00462963 h1^2+0.00204167 h2^2-0.0125 h3^2)^2
};

peqns = eqns /. {h1->h1[s], h2->h2[s], h3->h3[s], Subscript[σ,1]->s};
peqns //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\text{1.$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6}=100 \operatorname{h1}(s) \left(\frac{51
>    \operatorname{h2}(s)^2}{1400}-s\right)^2+0.0001` \operatorname{h1}(s)^2,\text{1.$\grave{
>    }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6}=4 \operatorname{h2}(s)^2 \left(\frac{6
>    \operatorname{h1}(s)^2}{7}-\frac{33
>    \operatorname{h2}(s)^2}{350}-s+0.00104167`\right)^2+\text{4.$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6}
>    \operatorname{h2}(s)^2,\text{1.$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6}=0.16` \operatorname{h3}(s)^2
>    \left(0.00462963` \operatorname{h1}(s)^2+0.00204167` \operatorname{h2}(s)^2-0.0125`
>    \operatorname{h3}(s)^2+0.001`\right)^2+\text{1.6$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7}
>    \operatorname{h3}(s)^2\right\}$

**Initial equations**

Next, to use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue), we need an initial condition, which we find using [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve):

```
p0 = First @ NSolve[(And@@peqns /. s->1) && h2[1]>0 && h3[1]>0, Reals]
```

> {h1[1] -> 1.*10^-8, h2[1] -> 0.000500521, h3[1] -> 0.624558}

There are many possible solutions, so I chose the one with positive numbers.

*In versions before M10, you may need to use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) instead of [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve):*

```
FindRoot[peqns/.s->1, {{h1[1],1}, {h2[1],1}, {h3[1],1}}]
```

> {h1[1] -> 1.*10^-8, h2[1] -> 0.000500521, h3[1] -> 0.624558}

**NDSolveValue**

Now, we can use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    Join[D[peqns, s], Equal @@@ p0],
    {h1, h2, h3},
    {s, 0, 5}
];
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At s == 0.001652735639801279`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

**Visualization**

```
GraphicsRow[{
    Plot[sol[[1]][s], {s, 0.002, 5}], 
    Plot[sol[[2]][s], {s, 0.002, 5}], 
    Plot[sol[[3]][s], {s, 0.002, 5}]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: this code give me error from po= First.....

Comment: is there another way to solve this problem

Comment: @MohamedKhalid You probably have lingering definitions. You could either quit the kernel and retry, or do `ClearAll["Global`*"]` and retry.

Comment: i tried quit kernel and clear all and i have the same error

Comment: I do two orders but i have the same error

Comment: @MohamedKhalid Perhaps you are using M9 or earlier? If so, I added a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution by solving one equation after the other.

First rationalize equations

```
eqs = Rationalize[eqns, 0] /. Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] -> s1;
```

Solve the first equation for h1, since it does not depend on h3

```
sol1 = Solve[eqs[[1]], h1]

(* {{h1 -> (1/
 9800)(-6502500 h2^4 + 357000000 h2^2 s1 - 4900000000 s1^2 - Sqrt[
 960400 + (-6502500 h2^4 + 357000000 h2^2 s1 - 
    4900000000 s1^2)^2])}, {h1 -> (1/
 9800)(-6502500 h2^4 + 357000000 h2^2 s1 - 4900000000 s1^2 + Sqrt[
 960400 + (-6502500 h2^4 + 357000000 h2^2 s1 - 
    4900000000 s1^2)^2])}}   *)
```

You get two solutions. Now insert one of that solutions into second equation and use FindRoot to get the dependance of h2 on s1.

```
fh2[s_] := 
  First@FindRoot[
    eqs[[2]] /. sol1[[1]] /. s1 -> Rationalize[s, 0], {h2, .01}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 200, AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 20]

LogPlot[h2 /. fh2[s], {s, -.008, .008}]
```

[image]

Get h1 now from the first equation

```
fh1[s_] := First@FindRoot[eqs[[1]] /. fh2[s] /. s1 -> s, {h1, .05}]

LogPlot[h1 /. fh1[s], {s, -.008, .008}]
```

[image]

Finally get h3 from the third equation

```
Plot[h3 /. 
   First@FindRoot[
   eqs[[3]] /. fh2[s] /. fh1[s], {h3, .5}], {s, -.008, .008}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Do the same with the second solution of sol1